# how to convert byte value into int in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, c, integer, byte

Please tell me how to convert bytes to NSInteger/int in objective-c in iPhone programming?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by convert bytes to int?

Comment: 'bytes'?  What kind of bytes?  Data? string? something over the net? xml? huh?

Comment: @bbum, the "value" does not come with an "s" in the question title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "Bytes"?
If you want convert single byte representing integer value to int (or NSInteger) type, just use "=":

```
Byte b = 123;
NSInteger x;
x = b;
```

as Byte (the same as **unsigned char** - 1 byte unsigned integer) and NSInteger (the same as **int** - 4 bytes signed integer) are both of simple integer types and can be converted automatically. Your should read more about "*c data types*" and "*conversion rules*".
for example http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-programming-language-data-types.html

If you want to convert several bytes storing some value to int, then convertion depends on structure of these data: how many bytes per value, signed or unsigned.

Comment: this _is_ an objective-c question. NSInteger is defined in NSObjCRuntime.h and the first #import in NSObjCRuntime.h is <objc/objc.h>, so I consider the objective-c tag is ok. (Just my guess), the rationale behind this question is: someone new to objective-c may not see the difference between a NSInteger and a NSNumber at first sight.

Comment: NSInteger is a typedef, not an objective-C keyword.  It's still a plain C question.

Answer (score 5):

If by byte, you mean an unsigned 8 bit value, the following will do.

```
uint8_t foo = 3;   // or unsigned char foo...
NSInteger bar = (NSInteger) foo;
```

or even

```
NSInteger bar = foo;
```

Comment: Awesome that work for me. Thanks heaps, I have been searching ages for how to do this with hex. e.g. Sing8 foo = 0xF4 converting that to an int

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

```
unsigned char data[] = { 0x00, 0x02, 0x45, 0x28 };
NSInteger intData = *((NSInteger *)data);

NSLog(@"data:%d", intData); // data:675611136
NSLog(@"data:%08x", intData); // data:28450200
```

So, beware of byte-order.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger x = 3;
unsigned char y = x;
int z = x + y;
```

Comment: because you got it backwards?  Still not worthy of a downvote given the lack of quality of the question.

Comment: y is a byte. z is an integer. the question is "how to convert byte value into int in objective-c"... never mind. I'll get used to this... ;-)

Answer (score -4):

Use the "`=`" operator.

Comment: Can u show me with a small example? 
i want to knw is there any inbuilt method to convert bytes to int.