# Convert 1 byte to int Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, byte

I have an NSData packet with data in it. I need to convert the byte at range 8, 1 to an int. To get the data at that location I do the following.

```
NSData *byte = [packet subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 1)];
```

If I NSLog byte

```
<01>
```

How do I think convert this to an int? This is probably the most basic of questions but I am just not getting it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

With that data the int should be equal to 1. I am not sure if this has anything todo with Endian.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718712/how-to-convert-byte-value-into-int-in-objective-c

Comment: @Dinesh thanks saw the link, updated my question.

Comment: Can you make it clear what actually you want to represent as integer for <01> it is 01 or just 1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [-[NSData bytes]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/bytes) to get raw buffer and read from it

```
int i = *((char *)[byte bytes])
```

or use [-[NSData getBytes:length:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes%3alength%3a)

```
char buff;
[bytes getBytes:&buff length:1];
int i = buff;
```

make sure you are reading from `char *` not `int *`, otherwise you are accessing invalid memory location, which may or may not crash or provide correct result.

Comment: Yeah, have tried this. Still not working, updated the question.

Comment: "not working"?? what is your expected result and actual result?

Comment: Expected result is 1 actual result is 31211265